# Remove everything after first alphabet

Tags: c#, regex

**My Input:**

```
string input = "0173706W(L31T*am)ABOVEPOVERTYLINE(APL)"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
string outpput = "0173706"
```

Tried as of now

```
Regex.Replace(EditedFeild3, "[^0-9]", "");
```

This input sample is just an example from many different executions.

So what I'm looking for a RegEx which will remove everything after any alphabet or special character is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Using

```
EditedFeild3 = new string(EditedFeild3.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Hope It helps somebody else.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following RegEx

```
(.*?)[a-zA-Z].*
^^^^^             : Capture lazily
     ^^^^^^^^^^   : Match anything after first letter
```

To remove everything after first letter, replace the string by `$1`- first captured group.

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dJ2kZ9/1)

---

You can also use

```
^([^a-zA-Z]*)
```

And get the first captured group string.

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dJ2kZ9/)

Comment: I do not want to capture it, I want to remove it

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee try `Regex.Replace(EditedFeild3, "[a-zA-Z].*", "");`

Comment: well I already solved it using `EditedFeild3 = new string (EditedFeild3.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());`

Comment: Have another query if you can spare some time

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      string name = "0173706W(L31T*am)ABOVEPOVERTYLINE(APL)";

      name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('6') + 1);
      Console.WriteLine(name);

 }
```

Comment: Add some explanation